# Clarity Design - Customising Clarity CSS

Tags: css, vmware-clarity

I am getting started with  Clarity Design with Angular.
I am trying to cusomise styles thru 'style.css' which is the last entry 
in styles array in angular.json

My questions/observations are..

1. Reduce the Height of the 'header'  ?
2. 'content-area' seems to be having some padding..
3. 'sidenav' seems to be leaving too much margins, paddings to my liking...

How do I customise/override these in css ?  Been trying few things but to no avail. Am I missing somthing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well for 1 you're missing the code in the question. Please add some relevant code so we can help

Comment: Clarity CSS is not too difficult to override assuming you get the right selectors. Use your browser to inspect the elements you wish to override and see what selectors are used to target them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd suggest to read [the official theming documentation](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/themes).

In general each component has a file called `_variables.<component_name>.scss` that defines all the variables used by the specified component.

For instance [this file](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/clr-angular/layout/main-container/_variables.header.scss) defines the variable `$clr-header-height` that is the default header height.

This [other file](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/clr-angular/utils/_variables.global.scss) instead defines "global" variables.

Comment: ..sorry for the delay in looking up your answer.. I am not looking at anything major as far as customisation...just a few things..can I override default styles in my component css ? like space around input labels and inputs.. Moreover, I have to admit I am pretty weak in CSS etc..so with my limited knowledge I was hoping there is an easier way...like controlling padding,margin etc...

Comment: ..for instance, Please have a look at <https://i.postimg.cc/Bv4M64JV/screenshot.png>. I would like to control the space around headers(Form , List,[this may have somthing todo tiwth router-outlet in Angular also) and Input labels.. Mind you, I am generating this Grid and Form dynamically using clr-input-container, clr-datagrid etc..

Comment: Hi if you want to override standard values used internally by Clarity, you have to customize the theme.